# Discord.py 2.0 - Button showing before message finishes editing view

Tags: discord.py

I'm hosting my bot online and sometimes messages take time to edit their own View components which is fine. The problem is when i modify a view by calling

```
await message.edit(view=...)
```

, the new button/select components are displayed instantly but their callbacks are not operational because the message editing is taking some time to complete. Thus, unknown interaction error tends to occur when clicking on the button a little too early, the callbacks are not being called, and I need to wait to re-click.

My question is : Is it possible to wait for a message.edit() to fully complete before showing the buttons, or is there another way to solve this issue?

Code sample :

```py
async def throw_dice(self,ctx):  
    try :
        superself = self
        async def action(superself):
            ...
        if isinstance(self.current,PlayerDiscord) :
            class myButton(ui.Button):
                def __init__(self,label,style,row=None):
                    super().__init__(label=label,style=style,row=row)
                            
                async def callback(self,interaction):
                        await interaction.response.defer()
                        nonlocal superself
                        if interaction.user.id==superself.current.member.id: 
                            self.view.stop()
                            await superself.msg_play.edit(view=None)  
                            await action(superself)                                
            
            self.view = FRPGame.myView(ctx,self) #Create new view
            self.view.add_item(myButton("\U0001F3B2",style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary))     
            #self.msg_play stores the message
            await self.msg_play.edit(content=self.content,view=self.view) #<-- problem is this single line
        else :
            ...
    except BaseException :
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please send your entire code so we can see what could be done

```py
#code here
asyncio.sleep(10) #Will wait 10 seconds before sending
```

Comment: I have edited in

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wait_for method to wait for the message to be edited. You can then use the message.edit method to edit the message and add the buttons.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
DiscordComponents(bot)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Hello")
    await message.edit(content="Hello World")
    await message.edit(components=[
        Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Red"),
        Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Green"),
        Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Blue")
    ])

bot.run("token")
```

This uses discord-components, which you can get here:
https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components

Comment: I use Rapptz to manage components, I noticed that when I call 'await message.edit(view=...)', it takes around 3 seconds to complete but the new buttons have already instantly appeared during the awaiting. It's like showing a button without the callbacks fully loaded which would likely produce errors because we clicked on it when the edit was still processing